# Logic behind the custom comparator for std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to write a custom comparator for the following priority queue:

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>,cmp> pq;
```

The first `int` in the pair is the key, and the second `int` is the count of the key. I want my priority queue to put the pair with the largest count at the top.

The following is my functor that has fulfilled my need:

```
class cmp{
public:
   bool operator()(const pair<int,int> a, const pair<int,int> b)const{
        return a.second < b.second;
    }

};
```

I do not quite understand why this is the correct way to do it.
Why the comparator returns `a.second < b.second` instead of `a.second > b.second`, since I want to put the pair with the most count at top?
And how the priority queue will actually utilize this comparator?

Comment: For consistency.  All the container sorting function prototypes are expected to be "less than" comparisons.  However, priority_queues return the "biggest" thing as the top.  In other words, the priority queue is "reading from the back".

Comment: The purpose of the comparator is to determine "less" state between two arguments presented. That's *all* it does.  Stop thinking of it a "this determines whether `a` comes before `b` in the queue". E.g. if `cmp{}(a,b)` answers true, it means `a` is "less" than `b`, but it also means the obvious counterpart: `b` is "greater" than `a`, and therefore will be closer to top in the queue as dictated by the internals of the priority_queue adapter.

Comment: How about you guys write an answer instead of answering in a comment? Btw. I would like to point out that the comparator should take const references.

Comment: @ypnos, what is the point of taking a reference to a pair of `int`s? It is likely to be passed in a single register, and when you take it by value, you avoid indirection in the comparator.

Comment: @Evg const& gives the compiler the biggest range of options for optimization. It might still pass the pair in a register, where possible. It might pass a pointer when a register is not viable. And the indirect addressing comes for free on most platforms. But the most important point, the signature of the function expresses its intentions, giving full power to the compiler and less power for the programmer to do mistakes (e.g. doing a `=` 'comparison' on a struct member instead of `==`).

Comment: @ypnos What does "it might still pass" mean? If the function is not inlined, `const&` has to be passed in some fixed way that does not depend on the function's body.

Comment: @Evg The function as shown by OP is an inline function as it is defined within the functor's declaration. Which is the typical way to do it with functors. Writing a functor in a way the operator can not be inlined by the compiler would give you a real performance hit.

Comment: @ypnos It is `inline`, but whether it is inlined (in the code replacement sense) is up to the compiler to decide. My first question was about the case when it is not inlined (otherwise, there is nothing to pass). I don't see the benefit of using `const T&` instead of `const T` for a pair of `int`s.

Comment: Right. Well, as you were so concerned with instructions I tried this with GCC 9.2 on AMD64, non-implicit function: https://godbolt.org/z/vfkwxC You can see the const& version saves an instruction (but, with -O0, which is crazy, it would need two more). For me the benefit really is: "the signature of the function expresses its intentions, giving full power to the compiler and less power for the programmer to do mistakes", given that an std::pair is not a primitive type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)'s documentation:

> Note that the `Compare` parameter is defined such that it returns `true` if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last.

The same happens with [`std::make_heap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap): providing a comparator that returns `a < b` – what [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) does – results in this function template building a *max-heap*, i.e., the element with the highest key is at the top of the heap. If you want to build a *min-heap*, you have to pass `operator>` instead of `operator<` or still, use `operator<` but flip the operands.

To conclude, both `std::priority_queue` and the function templates for dealing with binary heaps sort their elements so that the top corresponds to the *element with the highest key*. How two keys compare to each other is, however, up to you. You can control this by providing a custom comparator.